# Make a UIImage fit into 2 UITableViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have my `UITableView` with 2 headers on it. These 2 headers are on top of my `UITableView`. My first header have an `UIImageView` with a blurred image on the background.

I'd like this `UIImageView`to enter into my second header.

I don't just want to copy it, I want it to show me the rest of the image into my second header.

I did try a few things but I failed. I did not find any solution on stack neither, or maybe I used the wrong key words.

Thanks

Comment: Split the UIImage into two and use two UIImageViews?

Comment: The thing is that these are 2 headers. So I need the background image to disapears with the first header when i'm scrolling. I'm more looking for a way to make the image draw into the second header and disappear when scrolling. + the background image changes according to the image the user picks on real time.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Or a mockup image of what you mean?